# How to increase size limit of embedded ZooKeeper in Solr Cloud 8.4.0

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am running Solr in Docker and facing error about reaching the size limit of Zookeeper

```
NIOServerCnxn Exception causing close of session 0x100015d298b0002: Len error 2248387
```

I have follow the document https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_4/setting-up-an-external-zookeeper-ensemble.html#configuring-jute-maxbuffer-for-zookeeper-clients but no luck

The default size limit is 1MB -> https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/8.4.0/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/cloud/autoscaling/sim/SimDistribStateManager.java#L236

Here is the command i use to start solr

```
$ solr start -cloud -p 8984 -s "/opt/solr/example/cloud/node1/solr" -V
Using Solr root directory: /opt/solr
Using Java: /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.6+10, mixed mode)
Configuring SolrCloud to launch an embedded Zookeeper using -DzkRun

Starting Solr using the following settings:
    JAVA            = /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java
    SOLR_SERVER_DIR = /opt/solr/server
    SOLR_HOME       = /opt/solr/example/cloud/node1/solr
    SOLR_HOST       = 
    SOLR_PORT       = 8984
    STOP_PORT       = 7984
    JAVA_MEM_OPTS   = -Xms2G -Xmx6G
    GC_TUNE         = -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=250 -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
    GC_LOG_OPTS     = -Xlog:gc*:file=/opt/solr/example/cloud/node1/solr/../logs/solr_gc.log:time,uptime:filecount=9,filesize=20M
    SOLR_TIMEZONE   = UTC
    CLOUD_MODE_OPTS = -DzkClientTimeout=15000 -DzkRun
    SOLR_OPTS       = -Dsolr.environment=prod -Djute.maxbuffer=536870912 -Xss256k -Dsolr.jetty.https.port=8984


Warning: Available entropy is low. As a result, use of the UUIDField, SSL, or any other features that require
RNG might not work properly. To check for the amount of available entropy, use 'cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail'.

Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running on port 8984 [/]  
Started Solr server on port 8984 (pid=2512). Happy searching!
```

the option **jute.maxbuffer** have been set, but i still facing the error about size limit

My maximum file is only 2.1M

When i remove all the file upper 1M, the solr cloud running normal

Am i missing something ?

Thank you for reading all of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this command to spin up solr in docker

```
docker run -d -p 8983:8983 -e SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms2G -Xmx6G " -e SOLR_OPT="-Djute.maxbuffer=0x300000" -t solr:8.4.0
```

This will not work, after digging a little bit, i found the the SOLR_JAVA_MEM will over the SOLR_OPT, this command will work for who working on docker (this max file will be 3MB"

```
docker run -d -p 8983:8983 -e SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms2G -Xmx6G -Djute.maxbuffer=3145728" -t solr:8.4.0"
```

You will need to change the 0x200000 to real number base on this https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/8.4.0/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/cloud/autoscaling/sim/SimDistribStateManager.java#L237